# How to execute curl with json inside unix script by properly balancing brace/bracket

Tags: json, bash, curl, brackets, curly-braces

Ho to assign variables to curl which has a json format.  Echo the curl command and then execute.

The actual command I am trying to execute inside the script as below

```
curl --location 'url' --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"body": {"instruction":"START"}}'
```

The code snippet in the script is as below

```
iterationid=12345
domain_name=abcd
service=xyz
api_to_trigger="http://$domain_name/system/services/$service"
curl="curl --location '$api_to_trigger' --header \"Content-Type: application/json\" --data '{\"body\": {\"instruction\":\"START\"}}'"

echo $iterationid $curl
output=$($curl)
echo $iterationid $output
```

The mandatory requirement is to print the fully formed curl command along with the iteration id and also print the fully output of curl along with iteration id.

When i execute the script i get

```
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 24
```

Comment: Use the `jq` tool to create JSON, it can insert variable values. Don't try to do it with basic string processing, it's very hard to get the escaping correct.

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia?noredirect=1&lq=1 regarding quotes in a variable.

Comment: the `curl` variable is a command.  Might it be better implemented as a shell function, rather than a string?

Comment: You might want to read [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Don't try to store shell syntax (like commands with quotes in them) in variables. There are ways to do it, but it's full of traps and hard to get right unless you understand shell parsing *really really well*. Generally, the best answer is: just don't do that. Variables are for storing data, functions are for storing commands.